# How to do live reloading / automatic page refresh in elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to learn elm programing language from [here.](http://courses.knowthen.com/courses/elm-for-beginners/lectures/1254140) And it bugs me to manually do page refresh with every little change.

I see that elm-reactor doesn't support live realoading anymore. But what can i do unthil the next release?

Comment: https://github.com/moarwick/elm-webpack-starter supports Hot Module Reloading. very handy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use [elm-live](https://github.com/tomekwi/elm-live).

It is very simple and easy to use if you are just compiling Elm to js.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved! - gulp magic saves the day!**

(this solution works only with Chrome) Here is what I did - based [on this](https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/3ur5js/is_there_a_way_to_have_elm_reload_on_save_without/): ( Thanks janiczek !! :))

1. Inside your root directory add a new file named `gulpfile.js`
2. Paste this content inside:

**gulpfile.js:**

```
evar gulp = require('gulp');
var elm  = require('gulp-elm');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var path = ['*.elm']; // here you adjust the path according with your needs.
                      // For ex: 'scr/**/*.elm' - maps to every folder and file nested inside the src folder.
gulp.task('elm-init', elm.init);

gulp.task('elm', ['elm-init'], function(){
  return gulp.src(path)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(elm())
    .pipe(concat('elmapp.compiled.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('default',['watch']);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(path,['elm']);
});
```

3. You must have gulp installed globally if not run:

   ```
    npm install gulp -g
   ```
4. Install the gulp dependencies:

   ```
    npm install gulp-elm gulp-concat gulp-plumber gulp-livereload
   ```
5. Install [this extension: (chrome only)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei)
6. run `elm-reactor` and open your page in Chrome.
7. From inside your terminal, at root directory (or wherever your gulpfile.js is) run: `gulp`
8. With the elm page tab open, Press LiveReload button on the Chorme Extension. like below and make sure it says:

[image]

9. You are good to go! :)

Elm compiler doesn't like `.js` files around, so you will still see 2 errors. Ignore them. For me , everything else works as expected.